# How can the input type select the output and support a union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got the following code that can take an iterable or async iterable and gives an object of the same type back. It also has a number that can optionally be curried.

```
function _buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T> {
  throw new Error('not important')

}

function* syncBuffer<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T> {
  throw new Error('not important')
}

export function buffer<T>(
  size: number
): {
  (curriedIterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T>
  (curriedIterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T>
  (curriedIterable: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>
}
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T>
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T>
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable?: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>) {
  if (iterable === undefined) {
    return <R>(curriedIterable) => buffer<R>(size, curriedIterable)
  }
  if (iterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]) {
    return _buffer(size, iterable as AsyncIterable<T>)
  }

  return syncBuffer(size, iterable as Iterable<T>)
}


function run(a: AsyncIterable<any>) {
  return buffer(4, a)
}


function run(a: AsyncIterable<any> | Iterable<any>) {
  return buffer(4, a)
  return buffer(4)(a)
}
```

However I get the following type error on compile.

```
Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.ts(2394) 

// in reference to 
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>
```

However that doesn't seem to be the case? If I remove that overload signature I can't call the function with a union when I don't know which one it is.

Comment: By the way, sometimes when you find yourselves worrying about overloads and unions of parameter types, it is an indication that you should use generics and conditional types instead.  That is, overloads `f(a: T): U; f(a: V): W;` can be replaced with something like `f<X extends T | V>(a: X): X extends T ? U : W;` and you get calls of unions for free.  But that route might be more confusing to you so I won't elaborate unless you really need it.

Comment: Please do elaborate! I'm quite interested in learning more here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a separate answer because it presents a different approach.  One of the problems people sometimes run into with overload signatures is that they [don't always behave intuitively with unions of parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).  Here's a silly example:

```
// call signatures
function foo(x: string): number;
function foo(x: number): string;
// implementation
function foo(x: string | number): number | string {
  return (typeof x === 'string') ? x.length : "a".repeat(x);
}
```

The function `foo()` takes a `string` and returns a `number`, or takes a `number` and returns a `string`.  And this works as expected:

```
const num: number = foo("string"); // okay
const str: string = foo(12345); // okay
```

But people expect that you can pass it something of type `string | number` and get a value of type `number | string` out.  Sometimes this expectation comes from confusing the implementation signature with the call signature, other times it just seems like the compiler should be able to select multiple overloads and perform a unification of them.  But this doesn't happen.  The compiler picks just one overload signature (at least as of TS3.3, anyway.  It used to be impossible to call a union of function types, but [now you can](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)... well, with [caveats](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#caveats).  Perhaps eventually overload unification will happen):

```
const oops: string | number = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "string" : 12345); // error!
```

The suggestion in my other answer is to fix this by adding a call signature specifically corresponding to the union.  And that does work:

```
function foo(x: string): number;
function foo(x: number): string;
function foo(x: string | number): number | string; // added
function foo(x: string | number): number | string {
  return (typeof x === 'string') ? x.length : "a".repeat(x);
}

const num: number = foo("string"); // okay
const str: string = foo(12345); // okay
const oops: string | number = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "string" : 12345); // okay
```

But there is another way.  You can use [generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to take the place of the three call signatures, like this:

```
function foo<X extends string | number>(x: X): X extends string ? number : string;
function foo(x: string | number): number | string {
  return (typeof x === 'string') ? x.length : "a".repeat(x);
}

const num: number = foo("string"); // okay
const str: string = foo(12345); // okay
const oops: string | number = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "string" : 12345); // okay
```

Why does that work?

Well, the generic type `X` will be inferred to be any subtype of `string | number` based on the passed-in parameter.  For `foo("string")`, `X` is inferred as the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) type `"string"`.  For `foo(12345)`, `X` is inferred as the [numeric literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) type `12345`.  And in the call with `Math.random()`, `X` is inferred as `"string" | 12345`.  So all the calls should succeed.

What do they return?  That's where the conditional type comes in.  The type `X extends string ? number : string` means that if `X` is a subtype of `string`, then the conditional type will be `number`.  Otherwise the conditional type will be `string`.  So for `foo("string")`, `X extends string` is true, and the return type is `number`.  For `foo(12345)`, `X extends string` is false, and the return type is `string`.  And what about that union type with `Math.random()`?  Well, because conditional types [distribute over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types), it ends up becoming `number | string` as desired.

You may or may not want to do something similar with your function:

```
type MaybeIterable<T> = AsyncIterable<T> | Iterable<T>;
type UnmaybeIterable<M extends MaybeIterable<any>> = M extends Iterable<infer T> ? Iterable<T> : M extends AsyncIterable<infer T> ? AsyncIterable<T> : never;
type CurriedBufferResult = {
  <M extends MaybeIterable<any>>(curriedIterable: M): UnmaybeIterable<M>
 };
export function buffer(
  size: number
): CurriedBufferResult;
export function buffer<M extends MaybeIterable<any>>(size: number, iterable: M): UnmaybeIterable<M>;
export function buffer(size: number, iterable?: MaybeIterable<any>): CurriedBufferResult | UnmaybeIterable<any>
{
  // impl here
  return null!;
}
```

Is that what you want?  Not sure.

Comment: This worked better for the reasons you described. I had to introduce a type for the iterable as I didn't want it to be any, but it worked! I have to study this a bit https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Answer (score 1):

Function [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) in TypeScript split the function signature up into two sides: one is the list of *call* signatures, seen by the callers of the function. These are also just called "overload signatures".   There can be one or many of these.  Call signatures have no body.

The other side is the *implementation* signature, seen by the implementation of the function *and not by the callers*.  There can be only one implementation signature.   The implementation signature must have a body.

Call signatures must come before the implementation signature.  The implementation signature must be "compatible with" the call signatures (e.g., the implementation signature cannot require a parameter not supplied by any call signature), but they are not the same thing.

---

Your problem: you are trying to treat the implementation signature as a call signature.

The fix: add an additional call signature at the end of the list.  It can be the same as the implementation signature:

```
// call signatures:
function foobar<T>(foo: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterable<T>;
function foobar<T>(foo: Iterable<T>): Iterable<T>;
// add the following call signature
function foobar<T>(foo: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>;

// implementation signature:
function foobar<T>(foo: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>) {
  return foo
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

Updated to deal with new form:

```
type CurriedBufferResult<T> = {
  (curriedIterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T>
  (curriedIterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T>
  (curriedIterable: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>
};
export function buffer<T>(
  size: number
): CurriedBufferResult<T>;
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: AsyncIterable<T>): AsyncIterableIterator<T>
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableIterator<T>
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>
export function buffer<T>(size: number, iterable?: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>):
Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T> | CurriedBufferResult<T> 
{
  // impl here
  return null!;
}
```

This is the same explanation as before, but I've explicitly annotated the implementation signature return type to show the intent that it will subsume the possible return types of the call signatures.  This is part of making sure the call signatures and implementation signature are compatible.

It's now up to you to make sure the implementation (in `// impl here`) conforms to that annotation.  The problem you were probably seeing is that your function implementation didn't actually return the type annotated above, and the inferred implementation return type did not match the call signatures.

Good luck again.

Comment: It does solve my simplified example but not the full example for some reason. I'll update my post to include everything.